# Failed to connect to confluent cloud kafka topic using Data Stream connector Kafka Source, which has schema registry protected by basic user auth

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, basic-authentication, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to connect to the topic in the confluent cloud which has a schema registry protected by basic auth. The topic has an Avro schema attached to it. I am adding this as I could not find an answer on Stack Overflow so this could come in handy to other devs looking for the same.

```
Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<>();
configMap.put("basic.auth.user.info", "<SCHEMA_KEY>:<SCHEMA_SECRET>");
        
KafkaSource<T> source = KafkaSource.<T>builder()
.setProperties(consumerConfig)
.setTopics("exampleTopic")
.setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
.setValueOnlyDeserializer(ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(T.class,
                        "schema registry URL",
                        configMap))
.build();
```

This gives the 401 error unable to authenticate to the schema registry. How can I add basic user auth? I tried various things like adding

```
configMap.put("basic-auth.user-info", "<SCHEMA_KEY>:<SCHEMA_SECRET>");
configMap.put("schema.registry.basic-auth.user-info", "<SCHEMA_KEY>:<SCHEMA_SECRET>");
```

but it did not work. I have found the answer by digging in the code of confluent kafka schema registry client where we have to add another config along with basic.auth.user.info which is:

```
configMap.put("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO");
```

Only once you put this setting in then the call to schema registry will have the basic auth added.